# Ajax / HTML5 / Servlet - error when Input type = password

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, servlets

I am doing a simple register form with JSP + JS (ajax) and Servlets.

My problem is that when the INPUT type is 'password' and not 'text' my Ajax.done method wont call but the .fail method is called. But when I change the Input type to 'text' I dont get any errors and my .done is called.

the Code :

HTML :

```
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <span class="close">×</span>
                    <h2>Registration</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="regform">
                        <div class="container logform inputss">
                            <h5>Username :</h5>
                            <input placeholder="Username" class="login_FormIn" type="text" id="rusername" required>
                            <h5>Firstname :</h5>
                            <input placeholder="Firstname" class="login_FormIn" type="text" id="rfirstname" required>
                            <h5>Lastname :</h5>
                            <input placeholder="Lastname" class="login_FormIn" type="text" id="rlastname" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container logform inputss">
                            <h5>Password :</h5>
                            <input placeholder="Password" class="login_FormIn" type="text" id="rpassword" required>
                            <h5>Repeat Password :</h5>
                            <input placeholder="Confirm Password" class="login_FormIn" type="text" id="rrpassword" required>
                            <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="submit" type="submit" form="regform" onclick="register()" class="btn btn-danger lgbtn">submit</button>
                </div>

            </div>
```

my JS

```
    function register() {
    var rfname = $('#rusername').val();
    var rlname = $('#rfirstname').val();
    var runame = $('#rlastname').val();
    var rpass = $('#rpassword').val();

    console.log(rlname);
    console.log(rfname);
    console.log(runame);
    console.log(rpass);

    $.ajax({
        url: "regisServlet",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            fname: rfname,
            lname: rlname,
            pass: rpass,
            uname: runame

        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.regis);
        alert('success')
    }).fail(function () {
        alert ('error')
    })

    ;
}
```

And my servlet :

```
    @WebServlet("/regisServlet")

public class regisServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Boolean regis ;
        String userName = request.getParameter("uname");
        String userPass = request.getParameter("pass");
        String firstname = request.getParameter("fname");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("lname");
        System.out.println(userName);
        System.out.println(userPass);
        System.out.println(firstname);
        System.out.println(lastname);

        CreateStudent temp = new CreateStudent();
        try {
            temp.createSt(firstname, lastname, userName, userPass, 3);
            regis = true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            regis = false;
        }
        System.out.println(regis);
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("regis", regis);
        write(response, map);
    }

    private void write(HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> map) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(map));
    }
}
```

If u need any addititonal info, I will gladly post it, I am frustrated with it)

Comment: So what is different in the request when you inspect it in the browser?

Comment: Thank You , U helped me found my problem) The problem was that in Html I typed type='submit' but took the information with Jquery.val();